# Delay in shoot (Unity and C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am making shooting in Unity, what I want is to make a little delay, for example: to be able to shoot in every 0.5 seconds. Check the script, I want my bullet prefab to appear (instantiate) after 0.5 sec delay.

```
private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
private float h = 0.0f;
public float Speed;
public Transform firePoint;
public GameObject bulletPrefab;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    if (h != 0.0f)
    {
        rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(h * Speed, rb2d.velocity.y);
    }
    if (h == 0.0f)
    {
        rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(0, rb2d.velocity.y);

    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        Shoot();
    }
}


void Shoot()
{
    Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How make the script wait/sleep in a simple way in unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056471/how-make-the-script-wait-sleep-in-a-simple-way-in-unity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should take you in the right direction, of course, this is only one of the ways to do it.

You can change `fireDelay` to change the rate of fire.

```
private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
private float h = 0.0f;
public float Speed;
public Transform firePoint;
public GameObject bulletPrefab;

float fireElapsedTime = 0;
public float fireDelay = 0.2f;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    if (h != 0.0f)
    {
        rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(h * Speed, rb2d.velocity.y);
    }
    if (h == 0.0f)
    {
        rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(0, rb2d.velocity.y);

    }

    fireElapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && fireElapsedTime >= fireDelay)
    {
        fireElapsedTime = 0;
        Shoot();
    }
}


void Shoot()
{
    Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's works fine. Can you give me a little explanation what fireElapsedTime and fireDelay variables do? I'm new to both Unity and programming.

Comment: Sure @jolskey , `fireElapsedTime` tracks how much time has passed since the player last fired, `fireDelay` is the amount of time before the player can fire again. By increasing/decreasing the delay you can decrease/increase fire rate respectively.