# Sleep 2 seconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a Unity sword game. I have it so when you click Mouse0 it plays an animation and changes attacking to True. I am trying to make it so after two seconds(Or after the animation switches to Idle) it changes attacking to False. The code I have makes Unity stop responding.

EDIT: I know the code is in an infinite loop, but I need it so when ever I click mouse0 it works, not just at the beginning of testing. Is there a fix/ better way to do this

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SwordSwing : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator anim;
    public static bool attack = false;
    private bool a = true;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(waiter());
        anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

        IEnumerator waiter()
        {
            while(a = true)
                if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
                {
                    Debug.Log("True");
                    attack = true;
                    anim.SetTrigger("Active");
                    anim.SetTrigger("Idle");
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
                    attack = false;
                    Debug.Log("False");
                }



        }

}
```

Comment: If the user doesn't click the mouse button, the coroutine needs to yield control (e.g. with `yield return null` somewhere inside your while loop). See [this article](https://answers.unity.com/questions/904427/waiting-for-a-mouse-click-in-a-coroutine.html).

Comment: `while(a = true)` is assignment, not comparison. As such this loop will never end. It will also never end because `a` is not modified inside the loop. The assignment of `anim` should happen before you start the coroutine, not after.

Comment: unity stops working because the while loop is infinite, remove it. If you want to wait for realtime seconds. 
``yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
attack = false;
``
. For frame delay (you can put it inside a loop to wait for more frames)
``yield return null;``

I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How make the script wait/sleep in a simple way in unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056471/how-make-the-script-wait-sleep-in-a-simple-way-in-unity)

Answer (score 0):

Add a `yield return null;` at the end of your `while` so it can returns from the Coroutine and finish the frame.

Also, replace your while condition by `while(a == true)` (with double `=`) or just `while(a)`:

```
while(a == true) {
  if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
    Debug.Log("True");
    attack = true;
    anim.SetTrigger("Active");
    anim.SetTrigger("Idle");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    attack = false;
    Debug.Log("False");
  }
    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: Yours should work but unity still just freezes when I click play and it stops responding