# How can I start a timer after collision?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I want to create a bonus object in my game. When player picks it up, a timer should start.

```
public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) //player collide with bonus
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Cube")
    {
        StartTimer();
    }
}

public void StartTimer(){

}
```

Comment: I mean, when you pick up this bonus, you start the timer (for example 5sec) and in this 5sec i want to add some action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The Unity way of doing it would be a coroutine.

```cs
public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) //player collide with bonus
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Cube")
    {
        StartCoroutine(MyTimer());
    }
}

IEnumerator StartTimer(){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    // DO STUFF AFTER 3 SECONDS
}
```

2. You could create a RunDelayed helper to simplify the syntax. My favorite by far. It makes the code look much cleaner. Read [my blog post](https://medium.com/@nosuchstudio/implementing-a-rundelayed-helper-in-unity-d359b757b2fa) on this and how to make it accessible in all your monobehaviours (through either inheritance or extension methods).

```
public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) //player collide with bonus
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Cube")
    {
        RunDelayd(3f, () => {
            // DO STUFF HERE AFTER 3 SECONDS
        });
    }
}
protected IEnumerator DelayedCoroutine(float delay, System.Action a)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    a();
}

protected Coroutine RunDelayed(float delay, System.Action a)
{
    return StartCoroutine(DelayedCoroutine(delay, a));
}
```

3. You could use C# tasks and background threads. In Unity I try to avoid them since they are not compatible with WebGL and you may face problems in players. I know Google's Firebase uses them, so for more complex async tasks, worth checking out. For your simple case I don't recommend them.

Comment: Note that the option 3 makes little sense. As there already are built-in ways for delaying something it would be a lot of implementation (and execution) overhead to run the delay in a thread just to dispatch an event after the delay passed back into the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

There are many solutions here! Depends a bit on your needs. Among the favorites for your situation would probably be

you can either use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

```
public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) //player collide with bonus
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Cube")
    {    
        StartCoroutine (Timer());
    }
}

private IEnumerator Timer()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (3f);

    // Something that happens after 3 seconds
}
```

---

You can directly turn the collision message itself into a Coroutine

```
public IEnumerator OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) //player collide with bonus
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Cube")
    {     
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (3f);

        // Something happens after 3 seconds
    }
}
```

---

Or you can use [`Invoke`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) in order to execute a method after a delay

```
public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) //player collide with bonus
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Cube")
    {     
        Invoke(nameof(AfterDelay), 3f);
    }
}

public void AfterDelay()
{
    // Something happens after 3 seconds
}
```

---

For more options and detailed information checkout [How make the script wait/sleep in a simple way in unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056471/how-make-the-script-wait-sleep-in-a-simple-way-in-unity)

---

If by start a timer you mean e.g. a countdown display then you should definitely go with a Coroutine like e.g.

```
public Text text;

private Coroutine timer;

public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) //player collide with bonus
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Cube")
    {    
        if(timer == null) timer = StartCoroutine (Timer(3f));
    }
}

public void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D col) //player left bonus before timer passed
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Cube")
    {    
        if(timer == null) StopCoroutine (timer);

        timer = null;
    }
}

private IEnumerator Timer(float durationInSeconds)
{
    var timeLeft = duration;
    while(timeLeft >= 0)
    {
        Text.text = timeLeft.ToString(F2);

        yield return null;
    }

    // Something that happens after the timer reached 0
    Debug.Log("Hello!");
}
```

Comment: In the second case that your turn the OnCollisionEnter2D into a coroutine, You forgot to turn void to IEnumerator :)

Note that `invoke` is not typesafe and will make your codebase dirty. The Unity documentation itself suggests using Coroutines instead of `Invoke`.

Comment: @HosseinShah thanks I typed it on the phone and forgot to make it `IEnumerator` :)