# Wait for some seconds before it executes further code in UNITY?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i have tried doing this :

```
void Update()
    {
        if (isWalkingTowards)
        {
            if (Vector3.Distance(character.transform.position,this.transform.position)<0.7)
            {
                **StartCoroutine(Example());**
                Instantiate(character, new Vector3(-6, 0, -1), Quaternion.identity);
                Destroy(character);

            }
        }
    }
    **IEnumerator Example()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(5);
        Debug.Log("This function should be read before it is instantiated or destroyed");
    }**
```

But it just instantiates and destroys object and after that it shows me that message!

Comment: Not sure I understand. Why don't you put `Instantiate` and `Destroy` calls inside `Example`, after the `yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(5);`

Comment: Well done on getting a solution - I don't know if anyone mentioned the reason to move the `Destroy` call inside the `IEnumerator`. The reason is because once the `IEnumerator` is called, the next line of code doesn't wait for it to execute before continuing. The delay happens within the `IEnumerator` function, dictated by the yield return statement you have. So you were destroying the object outside your delay.

Answer (score 2):

I should have done this:

```
void Update()
    {
        if (isWalkingTowards)
        {
            if (Vector3.Distance(character.transform.position,this.transform.position)<0.7)
            {
                **StartCoroutine(Example());**
            }
        }
    }
    **IEnumerator Example()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(5);
        Debug.Log("This function should be read before it is instantiated or destroyed");
        Instantiate(character, new Vector3(-6, 0, -1), Quaternion.identity);
        Destroy(character);
    }**
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a super helpful link on a bunch of ways to wait in unity: [How to make the script wait/sleep in a simple way in unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056471/how-to-make-the-script-wait-sleep-in-a-simple-way-in-unity)

Also, I think the issue you're currently running into is that the code won't wait for `StartCoroutine(Exmaple())` to finish. You have to put the code you want to execute before and after in `Example`.