# C# Unity wait for function to be called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an event function which is called by some library.

```
// Called when an event is received
void OnEvent(EventData data) {
    // something here
}
```

I need to make coroutine wait until the OnEvent() function is called and receive the EventData or timeout.

I could use a custom WaitFor... function like that:

```
IEnumerable WaitForEventOrTimeout(int timeout, outc EventData eventData) {
    // Something
}

IEnumerable coroutine() {
    EventData eventData;

    yield return WaitForEventOrTimeout(4 /*timeout in 4 seconds if nothing received*/, eventData);

    if (evnt == null) {
        // Didn't receive event because timeout happened, handle that
    }

    // Do stuff with received event
}
```

But I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056471/how-to-make-the-script-wait-sleep-in-a-simple-way-in-unity

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I wouldn't use a coroutine to achieve that, I'll simply use an EventHandler or a direct delegate, but if your requeriment is to "make a coroutine" I'll aproach it like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class SOExample: MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool OnEventCalled = false;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        //Starts coroutine to wait until OnEvent
        StartCoroutine(MyOwnCoroutine());
    }

    public void OnLibraryEvent(string data)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnLibraryEvent");
        OnEventCalled = true;
    }

    private IEnumerator MyOwnCoroutine()
    {
        Debug.Log("Waiting");
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => OnEventCalled);
        Debug.Log("Do stuff with received event");
    }
}
```

The key is to use the [WaitUntil](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitUntil.html) yield instruction, and use a custom flag, in this example I've used a simple boolean, but you can use whatever you want as a delegate.

Remember to set to false again the flag if you want to reuse it!

If you want to go further and create your own custom yield instruction try with [CustomYieldInstruction](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CustomYieldInstruction.html) class, but is similar under the hood.

**EDIT**: Can probably be better implemented but this aproximation with CustomYieldInstruction currently works:

```
public class WaitForEventOrTimeout : CustomYieldInstruction
{
    //used to call StartCoroutine inside this class
    private MonoBehaviour mono = null;                  

    private Func<bool> checkIfEventIsTriggered = null;  
    private float waitingTime = 0;
    private bool timeoutTriggered = false;

    //this will be checked continously while returns true
    public override bool keepWaiting
    {
        get
        {                
            return !timeoutTriggered && !checkIfEventIsTriggered();
        }
    }

    //Constructor called when "new"
    public WaitForEventOrTimeout(MonoBehaviour mono, Func<bool> checkIfEventIsTriggered, float waitingTime)
    {
        this.mono = mono;
        this.waitingTime = waitingTime;
        this.checkIfEventIsTriggered = checkIfEventIsTriggered;

        //Starts countdown to timeout
        mono.StartCoroutine(WaitForTimeout());
    }

    private IEnumerator WaitForTimeout()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitingTime);
        timeoutTriggered = true;
    }        
}
```

Use it like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class SOO : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool _onEvent = false;
    public bool OnEvent() => _onEvent;

    private void Start()
    {
        //Starts coroutine to wait until OnWaitForEventOrTimeout
        StartCoroutine(MyOwnCoroutine());
    }

    public void OnLibraryEvent()
    {
        //When LibraryEvent is called, set the flag to true
        _onEvent = true;        
    }

    private IEnumerator MyOwnCoroutine()
    {
        Debug.Log("Waiting");
        yield return new WaitForEventOrTimeout(this, OnEvent, 4);
        Debug.Log("Do stuff with received event");
        //Reset flag
        _onEvent = false;
    }
}
```