# Why do await Task.Delay(10); stops execution in unity Web-GL?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, async-await, unity-webgl

I am using `await Task.Delay(10);` in unity C# for delay .After build and run in Web-GL format .The execution stops at this line that has delay .When I remove the delay it executes.

```
while (XAxiscurrentXpos <= -izvalue) 
{ 
    await Task.Delay(10); 

    XAxiscurrentXpos += 0.001f; 
    Vector3 posx = new Vector3(XAxiscurrentXpos, XAxisposition.y, XAxisposition.z); 
    XAxis.transform.localPosition = posx; 
}
```

Comment: WebGL doesn't support asynchronous or multithreaded executions out of the Box... => [async - await and WebGL](https://forum.unity.com/threads/async-await-and-webgl-builds.472994/)

Comment: So what is alternative for this

Comment: Alternative for what exactly? If you just want [delay code in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056471/how-to-make-the-script-wait-sleep-in-a-simple-way-in-unity) there are many options like Coroutines etc or show your actual code otherwise ... Also there is [`PlayerSettings.WebGL.threadsSupport`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerSettings.WebGL-threadsSupport.html) which might be what you want to use but it's experimental and not supported everywhere

Comment: Don't update your question and completely change the subject ...  stick to your original question and get answers to that specific question .... and if you have a new question open a new one ...

Comment: Ok I will open a new one ... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solution by using UniTask. [UniTask](https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask) Link is here

Answer (score -1):

So now knowing what you are actually trying to do instead of your task at all you rather want to use e.g.

```
public class MoveObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform XAxis;
    public float desiredUnitsPerSecond;

    // This is called once a frame by Unity
    private void Update()
    {
        if(XAxis.localPosition.x <= -izvalue)
        { 
            XAxis.localPosition += Vector3.right * desiredUnitsPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

this moves your object with the linear speed of `desiredUnitsPerSecond` in its local right direction as long as it is left of `-izvalue`.

Comment: Ok . I am not using it in update function. But I will Apply it and Will check the results. Thanks !

Comment: `  bool Xpositive=false;
    void Update()
    { if (Xpositive == true)
        { if (XAxiscurrentXpos <= -izvalue)
            { while (XAxiscurrentXpos <= -izvalue)
                {XAxis.transform.localPosition += Vector3.right * 0.01f * Time.deltaTime;
                } }
    }`  And this bool is changing in below code ` public async Task ObjSupport_PositionArrivedAsync(string Coordinate, double Value){switch (Coordinate){case "X+":{
              Xpositive = true;              }break;}}` Now when this becomes true the update function do not go inside if block Am i doing it right?

Comment: Again .. **why** use `async Task` for this? There is nothing in it that needs to be awaited anyway ... Simply use a normal void method?

Comment: I have removed async Task but still the update is not going inside ` if (Xpositive == true)`